# resizing wpf label to primary screen width

Tags: c#, wpf

I have my label

```
<Label Content="$500"   Height="113" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,21,0,0"
     Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="Black" AllowDrop="False"
     Panel.ZIndex="1" Width="350" Foreground="#FFEFEFEF" FontFamily="Arial"
     FontSize="100">
```

and I tried this:

```
label1.Width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
```

but it doesn't work. how can I get the label to have the width of the `PrimaryScreenWidth`?

Below is the full code I have:

```
<Window x:Class="Game.Player1Screen"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Player1Screen" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>

        <Label Content="$500"   Height="113" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,21,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="Black" AllowDrop="False" Panel.ZIndex="1" Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}" Foreground="#FFEFEFEF" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="100">

            <Label.LayoutTransform>

                <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>

            </Label.LayoutTransform>

        </Label>

        <ProgressBar Name="ProgressBarTimer" Panel.ZIndex="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Foreground="Blue" Background="Black" MouseLeftButtonDown="ProgressBarTimer_MouseLeftButtonDown"
Value="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Maximum="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}">
        </ProgressBar>
          </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What kind of container is your Label in? And is there any other modifiers on it? For example, you mentioned in [another comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654486/#comment47451358_29654594) you were doing a transform on it. Is that a RenderTransform or LayoutTransform?

Comment: @Rachel i've edited the question so you can see the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done would work, or you could set it in XAML:

```
<Label Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}" />
```

However, the width of the label (its `ActualWidth`) will be constrained by the container it is in - no matter what `Width` is set to.

Comment: ummm. I just tried the Static binding as you suggested in xaml and the control doesn't show up.

Comment: I"m doing a rotatetransform. could that be causing the problem?

Comment: You'll need to post a sample that recreates the issue you're having. Without that we can only guess.

Comment: {x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth} indeed did work. For some reason the   <Label.LayoutTransform>

                <RotateTransform Angle="270"/> was giving me problems. so I removed it. Compiled. then re applied the layouttransform and it worked.

            </Label.LayoutTransform>